# I've accidentally re partitioned my hdd and can't open cub liniuc. How can I recover it using an Ubuntu live disc?

Tags: partitioning

So at done point I accidentally re partitioned my drives like an idiot,  obviously a noob. Im running from a live ubuntu disc.  I don't wanna lose my data on cub, or sda2. How can I fix this.  I need detailed instructions for the entire process

Comment: If you want detailed instructions, you need to provide detailed info. Start by fixing your spelling (e.g. "cub liniuc" -> "Cub Linux"), then add info about what exactly you've done, what state your HDD is in, and what instructions you need. You can [edit] your question to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a deleted NTFS partition with data](/q/171163/175814)

Answer (score 0):

DON'T write anything to that disk for now!

Boot from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and install `testdisk` and see if you can recover.

Go here for instructions... http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step <sub>[(Archived link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170614020726/http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)</sub>

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/726021)

Comment: @KazWolfe I understand your point, however, if you follow the link, you'll see that there's no way to do that.

Comment: It's an automated message. At the very least, please include a [web archive](https://web.archive.org) link to prevent link rot.

Comment: @KazWolfe I think that I did what you suggested... please look... is that correct... and what does it do?

Comment: The archived link is a more permanent revision of the website at the exact same time you've seen it. If the link dies, the web archive version can remain a feasible backup if actually bringing the data here is impossible.

Comment: It's a very well-known site and a good link, so I would bend the rules to allow it in this case.

Comment: @karel what rules needed to be bent for this answer? I don't understand. I posted an answer with a link to detailed instructions on how to use it. What more could I have done? I couldn't copy the lengthy instructions, nor even para-phrase them. And even if Kaz hadn't helped with the archive link, couldn't a reader just paste a "bad" link into web.archive.org themselves to find other locations for it? I see so many people putting links in their answer, without an archive link. Inquiring minds want to know :-)

Comment: A link only answer is often but not always an opportunity to copy the entire block of text, provide attribution to the source and block quote format it to show that it was copied from the linked source. This turns a link only answer into something more permanent. However the link in this case is already sufficiently "permanent" so I don't see the need to be finicky about using a block quote formatted text block copied from the source.